# How to make an enumerate list with a set margin

Tags: lists, margins, enumerate, enumitem

I simply want to nest lists for answering homework problems with multiple parts as such

```
\begin{description}
 \item[3]
 \item[5]
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \item
 \end{enumerate}
\end{description}
```

and to have the nested list all aligned. I can't find a way to do this automatically, and I know the answer may be simple but this is bothering me a lot. 
My document class is article and I tried using enumitem with no success.

Answer (score 4):

The `description` environment naturally has a 'hanging' indent after the first line, which is giving your 'undesired' output.

It sounds like it would be more appropriate to use an `itemize` environment in your particular case, which gives the following output:

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
 \item[3]
 \item[5]
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \item
 \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

If you want the first-level items to be **bold** then you can use the `enumitem` package to help

[image: screenshot bold]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize]{font=\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[3]
    \item[5]
          \begin{enumerate}
            \item
            \item
          \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some variation on @cmhughes's solution: load `enumitem` with the `shortlabels` option and use enumerate in both cases:

```
        \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries1. ]
         \item
         \item
        \begin{enumerate}[1)]
          \item
          \item
         \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
```

gives[image]

Or, if you want the labels of both lists at the left margin, use the same preamble and this code:

```
        Lalala…
                    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries1.,wide,labelindent = 0pt]
                     \item
                     \item
                    \begin{enumerate}[1),,wide, labelindent = 0pt]
                      \item
                      \item
                     \end{enumerate}
                    \end{enumerate}
        Lalala…
```

[image]